# I got a data frame using the melt function which is get the items by scraping data, how I can remove a specific column and add a column title?

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following code:

```
data_coverage_table = [[], ['Bodily Injury Liability', '$250,000 Ea Person / $500,000 Ea Accident', '---'], ['Property Damage Liability', '$100,000', '---'], ['Uninsured Motorist Bodily Injury', '$250,000 Ea Person / $500,000 Ea Accident', '---'], ['Identity Fraud Expense Coverage', '---', '---'], ['Glass', '---', '$50']]

    for row in data_coverage:
        cells = row.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=".//td")
        row_data = [cell.text for index, cell in enumerate(cells) if index != 1]
        data_coverage_table.append(row_data)
    texts = ["Limit", "Deduct"]
    del data_coverage[0]
    print(data_coverage_table)
    df = (
        pd.DataFrame(data_coverage_table[0:]).set_index(0)
        .set_axis(texts, axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False)
        .set_index("variable", append=True)
    )
    print(df)
    df.index = map("{0[0]}-{0[1]}".format, df.index)
    # df.index = map("{0[0]}-{0[1]}".format, df.index)
    with pd.ExcelWriter('AutoPersonal.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
        writer.book = load_workbook('AutoPersonal.xlsx')
        df.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test1', index=False)
```

the output result is the next one:
[image]

The expected result I want to be :
[image]

I tried to delete the first element in the list to remove the nan column the first time, then I tried to add an id in the melt function but then I got the key, error, I tried to concat or to drop the specific element but no one of the methods doesn't work and I don't have any ideas how I can manage this, I asked even chatGPT but some answers but there was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I found was to add this specific data in another sheet and then use another data frame to extract the data from the specific sheet.
Add the specific values and then write again in the Excel file.

The code:

```
data_coverage = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH,
                                         value='//h5[text()=" Other Coverages "]/following-sibling::table//tr[position()>=1]')

    data_coverage_table = []
    for row in data_coverage:
        cells = row.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=".//td")
        row_data = [cell.text for index, cell in enumerate(cells)]
        # print(row_data)
        data_coverage_table.append(row_data)

    texts = ["Limit", "Deduct"]
    # print(data_coverage_table)
    df = (
        pd.DataFrame(data_coverage_table[1:]).set_index(0)
        .set_axis(texts, axis=1).melt(ignore_index=False)
        .set_index("variable", append=True)
    )
    # print(df)
    df.index = map("{0[0]}-{0[1]}".format, df.index)

    with pd.ExcelWriter('AutoCom_resultsCoveredauto.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
        writer.book = load_workbook('AutoCom_resultsCoveredauto.xlsx')
        df.T.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    #End the first part of the code
    
    #Start the second part of the code
    id_value = id
    cale_excel = 'D:\\Python Projects\\Get_Data\\AutoCom_resultsCoveredauto.xlsx'
    cale_excel_2 = 'D:\\Python Projects\\Get_Data\\AutoCom_results.xlsx'

    sheet_name_to_read_1 = 'Sheet1'
    df_copy = pd.read_excel(cale_excel, sheet_name=sheet_name_to_read_1)

    df_copy['ID'] = id_value
    sheet_name_to_read = 'Othercoverage'

    existing_df = pd.read_excel(cale_excel_2, sheet_name=sheet_name_to_read)

    combined_df = pd.concat([existing_df, df_copy], ignore_index=True)

    column_names = ['ID' + str(col_name) for col_name in df_copy.columns]

    df_copy = pd.DataFrame(df_copy, columns=column_names)

    with pd.ExcelWriter('AutoCom_results.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
        writer.book = load_workbook('AutoCom_results.xlsx')
        combined_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Othercoverage', index=False)
```

The results from the first part of the code where I use the melt function will be:
[image]

The results from the second part of the code:
[image]